# Understanding PHP Object Type Comparisons

Tags: php, oop, tdd

Continuing to work through Kent Beck's Test Driven Development by Example and rewriting the examples in PHP.

Chapter 13 describes a test that should return true if 2 objects are of the same type. In the previous chapters the evaluation works, but for this one example I can't get it to pass, and I'm not sure why it fails.

Given a class "Sum" that implements an Expression interface:

```
    class Sum implements Expression {
    public $augend;
    public $addend;


    public function __construct($augend, $addend)
    {

        $this->augend = $augend;
        $this->addend = $addend;

    }

     // impl of Expression interface, but this smells to me, dupe implementation
    // also in Money
    public function plus($addend) {
        return new Sum($this, $addend);
    }

    public function reduce($to) {         
        $amount = $this->augend->amount + $this->addend->amount;

        return new Money($amount, $to);
    }
}
```

And Expression:

```
    interface Expression {
    public function plus($addend);

    public function reduce($to);

}
```

I'm trying to call a method on a Bank object (called reduce) whose first argument is a Sum object, which has its own implementation of reduce. However, the Java example specifies the first arg as an interface, not a concrete class:

```
    class Bank {

    // the book defines the $source param as type Expression, which is legal 
    // in Java but not in PHP
    public function reduce($source, $to) {

       return $source->reduce($to);
    }
}
```

and finally, my Money class:

```
    class Money implements Expression {
    public $amount;
    public $currency;

    public function __construct($amount, $currency) {
        $this->amount = $amount;
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    public function currency(){
        return $this->currency;
    }

    public function equals($compareObject) {

        return $this->amount == $compareObject->amount
         && $this->currency() == $compareObject->currency();
    }

    // static factory method that returns Dollar 
    // (reduces dependence on subclasses)
    static function dollar($amount) {
        return new Dollar($amount, "USD");
    }

    static function franc($amount) {
        return new Franc($amount, "CHF");
    }

    public function times($multiplier) {
        return new Money($this->amount * $multiplier, $this->currency);
    }


     // impl of Expression interface
    public function plus($addend) {
        return new Sum($this, $addend);
    }

    public function reduce($to) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

When running this test:

```
$sum = new Sum(Money::dollar(3), Money::dollar(4));
$bank = new Bank();

$result = $bank->reduce($sum, "USD");

$this->assertEquals(Money::dollar(7), $result); //FAIL
```

The assert fails stating that $result is type Money and not type Dollar, even though I have verified that the properties for each object match:

```
$this->assertEquals(Money::dollar(7)->amount, $result->amount);


$this->assertEquals(Money::dollar(7)->currency, $result->currency);
```

Is this an effect of the lack of ability to intrinsically cast objects as specific types? I haven't change the implementation for the subclasses, and the previous tests still pass:

```
$five = Money::dollar(5);
$this->assertEquals(new Money(10, "USD"), $five->times(2));   
$this->assertEquals(new Money(15, "USD"), $five->times(3));
$this->assertEquals(get_class($five), "Dollar");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two objects of different type can never be equal. PHP does not let an object decide itself if it's equal to another object, as java does with the equal-method.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

In your test cases you could call the eqauls-method yourself.

```
$this->assertsTrue( $result->equals(Money::dollar(7)) );
```

Comment: I ended up doing this - `$this->assertTrue(Money::dollar(7)->equals($result));` which evaluates to true but feels fragile to me, because I'm relying on my own implementation of object equality, rather than some intrinsic PHP method (which apparently doesn't exist anyway)

Answer (score 0):

This is more an architecture problem than a problem of using phpunit. I gave you 2 simple solutions but you certainly should improve your code with some design patterns.

**1.**

What is the point of defining a class `Dollar` if you have to pass "USD" to the constructor? Use the class `Money` instead.

```
// static factory method that returns Dollar 
// (reduces dependence on subclasses)
static function dollar($amount) {
    return new Money($amount, "USD");
}

static function franc($amount) {
    return new Money($amount, "CHF");
}

public function times($multiplier) {
    return new Money($this->amount * $multiplier, $this->currency);
}
```

**2.**

This is not logic that a Sum of `Dollar` return a `Money` with possibly another currency (if you do not have a conversion mechanism). You can change the method `reduce` of `Sum` like this:

```
public function reduce() {         
    $money = clone $this->augend;
    $money->amount = $this->augend->amount + $this->addend->amount;

    return $money;
}
```

**---**

With these solutions your test will work as expected:

```
$sum = new Sum(Money::dollar(3), Money::dollar(4));
$bank = new Bank();

$result = $bank->reduce($sum, "USD");

$this->assertEquals(Money::dollar(7), $result); // OK
```

Because this assertion checks the class of the objects and the equality of the properties.

Comment: while you may have a valid point I can't assume this isn't going to be done in the book, as I'm only about 2/3 of the way through, and Beck does significant refactoring throughout.